# chromeブラウザでGCPに置いたpythonコードからGETリクエストをすると、CORSエラーが出る

Tags: python, python3, cors, google-cloud-platform

こんにちは。CORSエラーの解決についてお聞きしたいです。

GCPへ置いたindex.html内にpyscriptというpythonコードを書ける言語を用いて
GETリクエストをしたとき、以下のCORSエラーが出ます。
CORSエラーを解決する方法を教えていただけませんでしょうか？

```
"Access to fetch at 'https:/xxxxxx.com/x/xxxx/xxxxx' from origin 'http:/[my GCP IP Address]' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."
```

nginxの設定ファイルは以下を置いています。

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
root /var/www/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name [my GCP IP Address];

location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        # CORS start
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, Authorization, Accept";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
        # CORS end
}
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

以下はGETリクエストを投げるpythonコードです。

```
from pyodide.http import pyfetch, FetchResponse 
from typing import Optional, Any

async def request(url: str, method: str = "GET", body: Optional[str] = None,
                  headers: Optional[dict[str, str]] = None, **fetch_kwargs: Any):
    kwargs = {"method": method, "mode": "cors"}
    if body and method not in ["GET", "HEAD"]:
        kwargs["body"] = body
    if headers:
        kwargs["headers"] = headers
    kwargs.update(fetch_kwargs)

    response = await pyfetch(url, **kwargs)
    return response
```

[試したこと]
・GCPのバックエンドのレスポンスヘッダーへ以下を追加

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
```

・chromeエクステンションである、"Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin 0.1.9"を追加

[ブラウザの検証機能]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Fiddler などのツールを利用して要求・応答をキャプチャして、期待通りになっているか否かを調べるということはしたのでしょうか？